# Typeset a kind of exercise list

Tags: lists, tasks

How to typeset this kind of exercise list:
[image]

A possible solution is to use the **tasks** package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=\arabic*.,label-format=\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}$
    \task $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

The output is
[image]
However, I would like the math formula is typeset in displaystyle by default. And I have to add `\displaystyle` in every `$...$`, which looks pretty tedious. Is there a good method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your exercise lists will just have math-only items you can set the `item-format` accordingly or even define a new environment for this. In both cases you can leave the `$`s away:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label=\arabic*.,label-format=\bfseries}

\newcommand\mathtaskstyle[1]{$\displaystyle#1$}

\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = \arabic*. ,
  label-format = \bfseries ,
  item-format = \mathtaskstyle ]{mathtasks}(2)

\begin{document}

% optional argument:
\begin{tasks}[item-format=\mathtaskstyle](2)
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}
  \task \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n
\end{tasks}

% dedicated environment:
\begin{mathtasks}
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}
  \task \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}
  \task \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n
\end{mathtasks}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}
\settasks{label=\arabic*.,label-format=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$
    \task $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}$
    \task $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need for `etoolbox` with a current LaTeX. You can do: `\AddToHook{env/tasks/begin}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}`